# What does this mean in this context ? しっかり甘えんぼアピールを忘れないところは流石だな。( MC's thought about his little sister )

Tags: meaning, nuances, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english

> しっかり甘えんぼアピールを忘れないところは流石だな。

**Context**: MC's little sister made a curry dish for dinner, but it was too spicy and MC can't even swallow it (although he loves spicy foods). After that he decided that he will order curry from a shop.

Hope someone can help me understand its correct meaning. (my guess is: "So my little sister still hasn't forgot to take advantage of her cuteness as usual." ? but i'm not sure)

Full context:

> MC「まあ、次から気を付けよう。時間もないし、たまにはデリバリーカレーを頼んで食べるか」
>
> 絵美里「ふみゅぅ……ほんとは、お兄ちゃんの作ったカレーが食べたいけど……仕方ないですよね」
>
> MC「それじゃ注文しとくから、絵美里は部屋で待っていてくれ給えっ！　あ、何カレーにする？」
>
> 絵美里「お、お兄ちゃんと同じカレーが……いいです♥」
>
> **しっかり甘えんぼアピールを忘れないところは流石だな。**

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is mostly right but the sentence has a little nuance of irony. So, means of it is ”In spite of you don't cook curry well, you dare assert your cuteness! Good grief...”. Moreover, MC probably thinks ”but she is so cute including such a behavior...”